# Использование одного admob аккаунта для двух разных аккаунтов разработчика

Tags: android, admob, google-adsense, инструменты-разработчика

Возникла необходимость создания еще одного аккаунта разработчика Android на другое имя. Уже есть существующий аккаунт с готовыми приложениями. Доход от этих приложений стекает в admob аккаунт и в консоль разработчика (доход от платного контента).

Не будет ли критично привязка к новому аккаунту разработчика старого admob аккаунта? Дело в том, что в новой консоли будут так же приложения с платным контентом, а значит придется создать еще один аккаунт продавца. И я так понял, что аккаунт продавца должен быть уникальный для каждого разработчика.

Хотелось бы избежать блокировки на пустом месте. Буду рад советам!